# Why does my pygame window crash after some time?

Tags: python, pygame, crash

Here's the code, i'm working on Atom. I've been using pygame for a lot of time, and that rarely happens. I never knew what the problem was, but i never needed to, until now.

```
import pygame
from random import randint as rnd
from colorama import Cursor
import math
import os
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (600,90)


pygame.init()
xsize, ysize = 700, 700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((xsize, ysize))
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

def dis(p1, a1):
    return math.sqrt((p1[0] - a1[0])**2 + (p1[1] - a1[1])**2)

inner = 0
tot = 0
pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255, 255, 255), (350, 350), 350, 2)

while True:
    pos = (rnd(0, xsize), rnd(0, ysize))
    if dis((350, 350), pos) < 350:
        color = (50, 255, 50)
        inner += 1
    else:
        color = (50, 50, 250)
    tot += 1
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, pos, 2)
    print(" pi = " + str(4 * inner / tot) + "\nnº dots: " + str(tot), Cursor.UP(2))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window freeze, because you do  not handle the events. You have to handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event), to keep the window responding.

Add an event loop, for instance:

```py
run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # [...]
```